# embedded html in php isn't working correctly

Tags: php, html

[My php Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8NY1.png)

[When i open the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIleK.png)

[After i submitted the form,it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqZ2F.png)

Comment: I am wondering why there is always a 'Notice' popping out?Ho can I solve the problem.Thanks

Comment: welcome to SO , do not put screenshots as your question

Comment: Okay.Sorry,I will change it.Thanks for the advice:)

Comment: take a look at [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
//if the calculate button is clicked them only the code will be executed
 if(isset($_POST["calculate_button_name"]))
   {
    $cityname=array("wIndianapolisw","New York","Tokyow","London"); 
    $from=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"wfrom"); 
    $to=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"wtom");  
    $distance=array(array(0,648,6476,4000),array(648,0,6760,3470),array(6476,6760,0,5956),array(4000,3470,5956,0)); 
    print "Distance from w4cityname[$from].” to w4cityname[Sto].• is w4distance[Sfrom][$to] .w miles"; 
   }

?>
```